# I'm trying to display errors when the form field are empty or not numeric values and stop the form from submitting when empty , What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
require_once "pdo.php";

$failure = false;

// Demand a POST parameter
if (isset($_POST['make']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['mileage'])) {

    // if (empty($_POSt['make']) && empty($_POST['year']) && empty($_POST['mileage'])) {
        // $failure = "Mileage and year must be numeric";
        // return false;
    // }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO autos (make, year, mileage) VALUES (:mk, :yr, :mi)";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> execute(array(
        ':mk' => $_POST['make'],
        ':yr' => $_POST['year'],
        ':mi' => $_POST['mileage']));
    // $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $make = $_POST['make'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $mileage = $_POST['mileage'];

    if (empty($_POST['make'])) {
        $_SESSION['make'] = $failure = "Make is required";
    }else {
        if(!empty($_POST['make']) && is_numeric($_POST['year']) && is_numeric($_POST['mileage'])){
            echo '<p style="color: green">Record inserted'."</p>\n";
        }else {

            if(is_numeric($_POST['year']) === false && is_numeric($_POST['mileage']) === false){
                $failure = "Mileage and year must be numeric";
                header("Location: autos.php?name=".urlencode($_POST['who']));
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
// If the user requested logout go back to index.php
if ( isset($_POST['logout']) ) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Automobile Tracker</title>
<?php require_once "bootstrap.php"; ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<!-- <h1>Tracking Autos for <a href="#"></a></h1> -->
<?php
if ( isset($_REQUEST['name']) ) {
    echo "<h1>Tracking Autos for  ";
    echo htmlentities($_REQUEST['name']);
    echo "</a></h1>\n";
}
if(!empty($_POST['make']) && is_numeric($_POST['year']) && is_numeric($_POST['mileage'])){
    echo '<p style="color: green">Record inserted'."</p>\n";
}

if ( $failure !== false ) {
    // Look closely at the use of single and double quotes
    echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($failure)."</p>\n");
}
?>
<form method="post">
<p>Make:
<input type="text" name="make" size="60"/></p>
<p>Year:
<input type="text" name="year"/></p>
<p>Mileage:
<input type="text" name="mileage"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
<input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">
</form>
<h2>Automobiles</h2>
<ul>
<?php 
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT make, year, mileage FROM autos");
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo($row['year']);
        echo " ";
        echo($row['make']);
        echo " / ";
        echo($row['mileage']);
        echo "</li>";
    }
?>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So far if I'm trying to submit the form with empty field i get the error "Make is required", but it's still submitting the form , and also If i add something into make field and nothing in year and mileage field i don't get the error "Mileage and year must be numeric" even if i add something that is not numeric i don't get the error for them.

**Please let me know what i did wrog (I just started learning PHP).
Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you're submitting the form input with **$stmt -> execute(...)** before you validate it. If you want to execute the entry only if the form input is valid, you could e.g. use the boolean **$failure** and change its value to **true** if the input doesn't pass your validating if-statements and execute the prepared SQL-statement only if **$failure** is **false** at the end of your validation.

Comment: if i add the " if " statements before the $stmt-> execute(...) my errors messages doesn't show anymore